# How can I see my pending transactions in the BSC pending pool?

Tags: web3js, binance-smart-chain

I'm currently trying to get data from the BSC pending transactions, so I have been using this coding lines to see the changes in the mempool:

```py
    web3_filter= web3.eth.filter('pending')

    transaction_hashes = web3.eth.getFilterChanges(web3_filter.filter_id)

    for tx in transaction_hashes:

        Datatx = web3.eth.getTransaction(tx)
```

Seems that it works, I can see new pending transactions that are added in the pool and refreshed in a while loop. But when I execute a "swapExactTokensForETH" to test and see my tx in the mempool it doesn't appear. What am I doing wrong! Is there anything I have been missing?